# Line chart in Qlikview need to set three background colors

Tags: charts, qlikview

I have a line chart in Qlikview plotted against some data. Now I have three different sets of limits. e.g. Limit1Min - Limit1Max, Limit2Min-Limit2Max, Limit3Min-Limit3Max. For all these three limits i need to set a different color in the background. so that I can see where my actual plotted data is lying. I need something very similar to below image in link:
[example](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=qlikview%20line%20charts%20need%20backgrounds%20with%20three%20colors%20stackoverflow&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIN751IN753&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=17uu8A_wiKz_FM%253A%252CgEX6wXNn6V7hvM%252C_&usg=__BAKNkBOK9HgLSx1JfCjH1FPFYPA%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1mY2P0MrZAhVCMo8KHdrbBe0Q9QEIPTAC#imgrc=17uu8A_wiKz_FM:) . Please let me know hoe to do it in QlikView.

Answer (score 2):

So the real trick is to make a combo chart, stack the bars and then set the clustering to 0.

My data isn't ideal for this example but you should get the idea.

This is the basic chart 
[image: Starting chart]

The expressions are just

[image: Limits]

I hardcoded my limits. Remember that because you are stacking them you need to use the difference not the absolute value. i.e. I want my lim 3 >70% and <90% so I made lim 1-Min = 60%, lim 2-Min=10% and lim 3-Max = 20%.

Then I want the bars to touch each other. So make sure they're stacked

[image: Stacked]

Then set the cluster distance to 0

[image: Cluster]

Result should be something like this

[image: Result]

There are lots of maths and tricks you can use to make the limits and deviations work that I'm not going to type out for you. These blog posts do a good job of that

https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-4245 (will probably require qlik community login)

https://qlikfit.blogspot.co.za/2013/03/qlikview-lean-tips-1-how-to-highlight.html (should be free to view)